# How can I add my vaccination record to Apple Health on iOS?

Tags: ios, health.app, wallet, health-kit

I have a PDF for my C19 vaccine, and would also like to manually enter the dates, doses, etc. of my other vaccines. Where can I do this in the Apple Health app?

I do not [see a place](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iphc30019594/ios) where I can upload my EU COVID Certificate anywhere in the deeper settings.

Is this available to European users?

Answer (score 1):

This is not available to EU users yet, even to manually add the info.  According to [Macrumors](https://www.macrumors.com/2022/01/28/ios-15-4-eu-covid-vaccine-certificates-wallet/), this feature is currently in the iOS 15.4 beta.

[image]

> When iOS 15.4 is released, users will be able to add a EU Digital COVID Certificate to the Health and Wallet apps by opening the Camera app, scanning the certificate's QR code, tapping on the yellow Health app notification that appears, and tapping the "Add to Wallet & Health" button. Vaccine cards in the Wallet app display a person's name, the type of vaccine they received, the date that each dose was administered, the issuer, and a digitally signed QR code. More detailed immunization records are accessible through the Health app.

Answer (score 0):

If you agree with an alternate solution, you may have your C19 Certificate in your wallet, using this site: https://covidpass.marvinsextro.de - it is claimed that most of the works done in your device - read the Privacy Policy link at the bottom of that page.